# Xcode 4.5 and Phonegap 2.0 reference issue

Tags: xcode, cordova

Yesterday I updated new Xcode 4.5, and I got an error in my build and I am not sure how can I even fix this.

Everything works fine if I build in simulator, but when I try to build for Archive for example, i get this:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/corotchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NJR_IR-ftjwhrqtxwedihfjrbjikbqqttkx/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/corotchi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NJR_IR-ftjwhrqtxwedihfjrbjikbqqttkx/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVURLProtocol", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

*and more errors bellow, which are the same*

Everything worked fine until u updated the Xcode, I had another issue before where I read the formums that I have to remove the "**ARMV6**" from the build settings, cause it is not supported anymore in new IOS, and after that I get this reference  issue.

I appreciate any help, 
THanks!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you also take out armv7s from the build settings, you should get it to build for you.

Edit: As per below: Fix can be found here via PhoneGap: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1360

Comment: Indeed; I suspect that the folks that run Cordova will eventually put out a build that includes v7s.

Comment: After this fixed I had another issue , it did not have landscape orientation and the fix I found Here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/KJmvRIajsm8

Answer (score 8):

Remove armv7s from Valid Architectures from both your project and Cordova(phonegap) project. Also set iOS Deployment target 4.3 or above in both project and Cordova(phonegap) project. After that Clean and Clean Build Folder. This will solve the problem.

Comment: Nice one.  Clear instructions, did it for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me until I set the deployment target to 5.0

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug already fixed at Cordova 2.2.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1360

Comment: cordova 2.2.0 hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 1):

Change the **Buid setting ---> Architecture  ---> Build Active Architecture** only ---> **Yes**
This solved my issue for using old cordova versions in new Xcode 5